# How should I add scheduler tasks to shell-like program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

Say I have a shell-like program:

```
int main(){
    while(true){
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        if (c=='a') task();
        else …
    }
```

Now I want to add a scheduler for the program. Say every 5 seconds it executes a procedure like `task()` as the main loop. However the scheduler can’t interfere the main loop, i.e. while the main loop is waiting for my input, the scheduler will still execute `task()` every 5 seconds.

Moreover, if I want to make the scheduler a plugin (say: DLL file), what should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to run the scheduler on a separate thread.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to make the scheduler a DLL file, the classes defined in main loop file cannot pass to the DLL. If I include them in DLL that seems to make no sense.

Comment: please show a [mre] of what you're trying to achieve and where you've got stuck

Comment: You can have threads in your dll.

Comment: Alternatively you can investigate using event loops like libuv or libev, which treat both the commandline input and the timer as events to be handled in a single event loop.